# How to calculate the worst case (Big O) of a program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

*Please excuse the intentional verbosity*

Here is a small program excerpt:

```
for i=1 to n
  j= 0;
  while(j<=n);
  j=j+1;
```

If I have to find the complexity(Big O) of this code:

I'll first count how many times the inner loop will execute which in this case is n+1 times because from 1 to n, it is n times and since j is 0, it adds to the while looping. So in total n+1 times for the while loop.

The number of times the outer for loop will execute is n times because from 1 to n, the total count is n.
Hence the grand total is n+1+n is 2n+1.

Discarding all constants it's big O(n).

Is it correct? The web page from where I found this example says the outer loop will run n(n+1)/2 times. I didn't understand this. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
For each value `i` is getting (and there are `n` of those), you run the `while` (inner) loop `n+1` times (j=0,j=1,...j=n).

Thus, the total number of times the line `j=j+1` is being executed is `n*(n+1)`, which is in `O(n^2)`